# php file_get_contents not working on server

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, connection-timeout

I have an issue when using `file_get_contents`

I need to get content from a url

```
$header=array();
$header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
$header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Pragma: ";
$opts = array(
                'http'=>array(
                            'method'=>"GET",
                            'header'=>implode('\r\n',$header),
                            'proxy' => 'proxy_address',
                            'request_fulluri' => True
                            )
                    );

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo $file;
```

The error message says: `file_get_contents(my url) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Connection timed out`

I tried a `curl` request, but get the same response. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your hosting company may block outgoing requests, check with them.

Comment: Have you tried the code on various hosts? It looks alright, only thing I can think of is your host / the external site not responding.

Comment: With other sites code worked correct,i think site,which i try parse blocked my requests (that why i add proxy) but it not help :(

Answer (score 0):

try to add timeout setting to your opts:

```
$opts = array(
                'http'=>array(
                            'method'=>"GET",
                            'header'=>implode('\r\n',$header),
                            'proxy' => 'proxy_address',
                            'request_fulluri' => True
                            ),
                'timeout' => 60
);
```

This example sets connection timeout to 60 seconds